# wxmaxima does not completely solve a derivative

Tags: maxima, wxmaxima

I don't know why wxmaxima doesn't give me the complete result, leaving an expressed derivative and not solving it

[image]

I don't understand what I could be doing wrong. If anyone can help me, thank you in advance.

Note: Wxmaxima version 19.01.2x ; Maxima version 5.42.2

Here is the code in text:

```
kill(all);
declare(V,constant,R,constant,a,constant,b,constant);
P:R*T/(V-b)*(%e)^{-a/(R*T*V)};
diff(P,T);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that Maxima uses only parentheses (i.e., `( )`) for grouping. Curly braces `{ }` denote sets, and square braces `[ ]` denote lists.

Try writing the exponential as `%e^(-a/(R*T*V))`, I think that should fix it.